# Types of standard prelude function when composed

Tags: haskell

I  have to find out the type of these functions

```
(.)(:) :: (a -> b) -> a -> [b] -> [b]
(:(.)) type error
((.):) ::
((:):) :: 
(.)(.) ::

(.):: (b ->c )->(a->b)->a->c
(:) :: a->[a]->[a]
```

I don't know what to do to find the type of ((.):).
These are old exam question and i am trying to learn how to find types when functions are composed. I have only been able to solve the first one.

Answer (score 1):

`(.)` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and `(:)` has type `a -> [a] -> [a]`.

`(x:)` is the same as `\xs -> x : xs`. In your case, `x` is `(.)` and thus has the type of `(.)`.

From this we can conclude that `((.):)` has type `[(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c] -> [(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c]`.

GHCi verifies this:

```
Prelude> :t ((.):)
((.):)
  :: [(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c]
     -> [(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c]
```

Comment: so i just have to change a in a -> [a] -> [a] with type for (.)

Comment: How should i think when i have (.) (:) because i think same thinking will help me solve (.)(.)?
i think i was just lucky on the first one.

Comment: @user2975699 In the type of `(.)`, remove `(b -> c) ->` (because you’re currying) and substitute the other `c` for `[b] -> [b]`.

Comment: (.)(.) 
in type of (.) ::(b ->c )->(a->b)->a->c I should remove b->c 
replace c with (a->b)->a->c

Answer (score 1):

You just use the same unification algorithm that the compiler uses (mostly). First you should rewrite the expression into a prefix form, working the `((.):)` example that'd be:

```
\p -> (:) (.) p
```

which eta-reduces to

```
(:) (.)
```

now

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(.) :: (y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z
```

hence you need to unify `(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z` with `a` which gives us a more specific type for `(:)` in the context of `(:) (.)`:

```
((y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z) -> [(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z)] -> [(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z)]
```

as this is plain function application, the rule is

```
f   :: a -> b
x   :: a
f x :: b
```

now that the type of `(.)` and the first parameter of the specialised `(:)` (intermediate) type are the same, you just cancel them out to get the resulting type for `(:) (.)`:

```
[(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z)] -> [(y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> x -> z)]
```

Comment: didn't get "this is then applied to (.); as the type of (.) and the first parameter of the intermediate type are the same, you just cancel them out to get:" this part

Comment: The intermediate type is the type of `(:)` specialised in its context here. The rule for function application is: `f :: a -> b` and `x :: a` then `f x :: b` (must be the same `a` though!).